# How can I merge AngularJS , React and Redux?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building an application using angular and redux (ngRedux). Now i want to use react instead of angular for improvement in performance. It is a huge application so it is not possible to build it from scratch. So i want to use the routing of angularJS (angular-ui-router) and as any "abc" state become active then the react component become load and this react component should use the pure redux against every single event.

How can i maintain my application accordingly that a single module is build in react-redux and connected to angular only through routing state. Keep in mind that the other modules of application should also not be disturbed.

Answer (score 1):

Well to render React components into Angular is quite easy. But I just assume you use `directive`or `component` from angular already.

So in the case of `directive` you could skip the whole templating "none sense" and let React handle that for you

```
module.directive("reactTest",function() {
  return {
    link:function(scope,element,attr) {
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) { super(props) }

        render <div></div>
      }
      element.replace(App);

    }
  }
});
```

So this how you would get React into Angular. Redux ist basically the same. You simple use the `connect` function of redux and off you go.

Comment: yes its nice but there is a clash occur between es5 and es6. Currently my application is built in es5 but the syntax you mentioned if react class is es6. how this clash can be solved?

Comment: oh you can use the non es6 syntax form react... React.creatClass({}) .... the JSX stuff get more complicated. you would need to use the non JSX syntax. React.createElement